# how to add cdrom in ubuntu16.0.4 server error comes "fail to fetch cdrom"

Tags: server

error related image is uploaded we want to install ATutor on Linux server Ubuntu 16.0.4  but we encountered errors as :some files not found or "sudo apt-get update" gives errors seen in attached image most important ERROR FAIL TO FETCH CDROM. How to resolve

[image]

Comment: Are you using a CD to install ATutor?

Comment: No I am not using any CD to install ATutor

Comment: Try deactivating the CD sources from the repositories. Open Settings, Softwares and Updates, Other Software, and deselect the first option, CDROM.

Comment: i have already resolved thsi issue the solution is write on command prompt 
"cd /etc/apt"  then type "ls" after this "sudo nano sources.list" sources file will open then insert a # berfore the line cdrom starts.After this press Ctrl+X then enter y and press Enter  the file will be saved in edited form.and the error will be solved.

Comment: Good. Why don't you write that as an aswser, so it can be marked as solved?

Comment: sorry i was forget about it. i am using stack first time so...

Answer (score 0):

i have already resolved this issue the solution is write on command prompt "cd /etc/apt" then type "ls" after this "sudo nano sources.list" sources file will open then insert a # berfore the line cdrom starts.After this press Ctrl+X then enter y and press Enter the file will be saved in edited form.and the error will be solved. –Or you can visit the this link for more clarity "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfyobrcSx1Q"